# What are examples of modular form of level $1$ (i.e. modular form on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$) with poles?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, modular-function, modular-group

I am thinking of Eisenstein series, $$G_k(\tau) = \sum_{(c,d)\in {\mathbb{Z}}^2-\{(0,0)\}}\frac{1}{(c\tau+d)^k}, \tau \in \mathbb{H} $$ because we don't sum over $(0,0)$, so I'd like to call $(0,0)$ a pole. Am I right or wrong?

My other intuition is the $j$-function because it's q-expansion shows it has pole at $\infty$; BUT some texts don't consider $j$-function as a modular form, they only consider it a modular function. So, if these two are not the right examples, could someone please direct me to the right ones?

Thank you very much!

Comment: When we consider modular forms, then we consider them to be holomorphic on $\mathbb{H}$ and also at cusps. So, there's no pole for modular forms.

Comment: Also consideration of $(0,0)$ as a pole seems to be wrong because division by 0 is not same as infinity; there needs to be some extra context for this consideration.

Comment: There's unfortunately some inconsistency in notation. Usually "modular form" implies "holomorphic everywhere (including cusps)" and "modular function" means "meromorphic everywhere" (which makes some sense because the only holomorphic modular functions are constant). Sometimes "meromorphic modular form" means that poles are allowed, sometimes it means they are allowed but only at the cusps. So 1/Delta (for example) would be a meromorphic modular form (in either sense) with a poly at the cusp $i \infty$.